# will apple reject apps that make use of the device id.?

Tags: iphone

I have developed an app that make use of the iphone device id and sends the same to a webservcise, as primarily my app uses device id to prevent unauthorised device access.
But i am in doubt  whether apple will reject the app bacause of this...?
Pls can anyone clarify my doubt...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UDID is a unique identifier for an Apple mobile device that is safe to make public. On the other hand, a device's serial number is not accessible through the iOS SDK and it would not be a good idea to tell your serial number to everyone.

There's no reason that Apple would reject an app for sending the UDID to a server (a lot of apps, such as those that use the Apple Push Notification Service, do this).

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily, as you also send the device ID if you want to register push events, but apple might not like that you run your own copy controls.

If you want something that comes closer to a official response try asking in the apple developer forums, the sometimes give semi-official answers there.

Answer (score 1):

Apple won't bother you over using the UDID unless you're making it publicly visible. As long as you don't do that, you'll be fine.